# Does document.getElementById('txt1').removeAttribute('ReadOnly') erase the content of 'txt1'?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this function at my asp document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">         
   function OnClientUploadCompleteFn(){
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt1').removeAttribute('ReadOnly');
   }
</script>
```

I trigger the function on `ajax:AsyncFileUpload`

```
<ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID="fuFile" runat="server" Width="250px" 
                   OnClientUploadComplete="OnClientUploadCompleteFn" />
```

I manage to successfully achieve my goal to enable the `txt1` when the client side upload completed.
 My problem now is that when I retrieve `txt1`, it returns a null value here:

```
obj.Details = string.Format(def.VAL_SPONSOR_ATTACH, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState[def.ID].ToString()),
         txt2.Text.Trim(), txt1.Text.Trim());
```

Where did I go wrong?

P.S.
I checked my code and all possibilities that my C# codes clear the textbox is gone(commented out).

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown us clears the value in txt1. How are you retrieving the value?

Comment: wait, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would happen if you set the ReadOnly property of your TextBox. The new value wouldn't be processed by the server on postback.

If so, in your server-side code, replace

```
txt1.ReadOnly = true;
```

with

```
txt1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

Comment: Actually I got it. I put `txt1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "true");` in my codes behind. That does the trick. Thanks though.